# Docker Remote API does not list containers

Tags: json, bash, docker, dockerfile

I have locally installed docker server which runs one container.

```
 CONTAINER ID   IMAGE   COMMAND      CREATED      STATUS      PORTS NAMES
 3d7ef4f6bb0a   debian "/bin/bash"  7 hours ago  Up 7 hours  0.0.0.0:80->2376/tcp   nostalgic_fermat
```

when I tried to use the docker remote API in order to get the information about this container I did not see the json output about the containers running on host.                  The result from rest call is:

```
wget -v 192.168.99.100:2376/containers/json/

--2016-01-16 23:57:20--  http://192.168.99.100:2376/containers/json/
Connecting to 192.168.99.100:2376... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9
Length: unspecified
Saving to: 'index.html.3'

index.html.3                                                    [ <=>                                                                                                                                        ]       7  --.-KB/s   in 0s     

2016-01-16 23:57:20 (297 KB/s) - 'index.html.3' saved [7]
```

What exactly I am missing?

The version of API is:

```
 Client:
 Version:      1.9.0
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   76d6bc9
 Built:        Tue Nov  3 19:20:09 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
```

**EDIT (RESOLVE)**

It appears that docker server requires SSL authentication. I was able to  authorized to docker localhost by providing the local docker server certificates.

The following command stores json file with information of all containers running on local docker server.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --ca-certificate ca.pem --certificate=cert.pem --certificate-type=PEM --private-key=key.pem --private-key-type=PEM https://192.168.99.100:2376/containers/json
```

Comment: I am assuming you are aware that your docker API doesn't run on docker API port 5555.  If that is the case, I would just try to hit it the API from the localhost, since I don't know that docker API binds to all addresses: "wget -v localhost:2376/containers/json" (same line but without final slash.) if you think you should be querying the default port 5555, then it should look more like: "wget -v localhost:5555/containers/json"

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I tried both requests with and without port 5555, but the result is the same:
wget -v localhost:2376/containers/json
--2016-01-17 01:32:11--  http://localhost:2376/containers/json
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:2376... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:2376... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: I've resolved the issue, check the EDIT section in my initial post. Thank you.

Comment: You're running this command on the node that is running docker, right?

Comment: can you post your finding as an answer, then this question can be closed as "answered"